# I want to post array of objects using Alamofire swift 4

Tags: ios, post, alamofire, swift4

this is the JSON  I am trying to post it has JSON array named Menus and inside it has menu objects

```
 {  
   "Menus":[  
      {  
         "Id":"5ae03b8e90435721f465050c",
         "Name":"testmenu2"
      },
      {  
         "Id":"5ae03f4490435721f465051b",
         "Name":"menu1"
      }
   ],
   "InStock":true,
   "Pricing":{  
      "Price":1000,
      "SaleEnd":"2018-04-20",
      "SaleStart":"2018-04-20",
      "SalePrice":120
   },
   "Sku":"chickenkoththutest",
   "PreparationTime":{  
      "MinCount":"0",
      "MinTime":"0",
      "AdditionalPerItem":"0"
   },
   "Name":"chickenkoththutest",
   "BusinessId":"5adda52c90435519b0c31aff",
   "Attributes":[  

   ],
   "Cuisines":[  

   ],
   "Description":"none"
}
```

and this is the method I am following but all other details are submitting excepting array of objects. First I convert objects into dictionary and append them in to a array. Posting single dictionary object is working but when I append them into array and try to post it cannot be posted .is there any way to post array of objects using Alamofire

```
    func AddMenuItem(deviceToken:String,Name:String,Sku:String,BusinessId:String,Pricing:Pricing,Menus:[Menus],Cuisines:[Cuisines],Attributes:[Attributes],Description:String,Instock:Bool,PreparationTime:PreparationTime,_ completion: @escaping (_ sucsessStatus:String, _ id:String,_ error_type:String)->()) {
    let headers = [
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + deviceToken,
        "Accept": "application/json"
    ]
    var categories = [AnyObject]()
 var attributeList = [AnyObject]()
    var cuisineList = [AnyObject]()
     var options = [AnyObject]()
      for menu in Menus{
            if(Menus.count != 0){
               let Cat: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
                Cat.setValue(menu._Id, forKey: "Id")
                Cat.setValue(menu.Name, forKey: "Name")
           //  let array = JSON(Cat)
                categories.append(Cat)}
            }

    for cuisine in Cuisines{
        if(Cuisines.count != 0){
            let Cat: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
            Cat.setValue(cuisine._Id, forKey: "Id")
            Cat.setValue(cuisine.Name, forKey: "Name")
          //  let array = JSON(Cat)
            cuisineList.append(Cat)}
    }

    for attr in Attributes{
        if(Attributes.count != 0){
            let Cat: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
            Cat.setValue(attr._Id, forKey: "Id")
            Cat.setValue(attr.Name, forKey: "Name")
           // let array = JSON(Cat)
            attributeList.append(Cat)}
    }

    for option in OptioList.options{
        if(OptioList.options.count != 0){
            let Cat: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
            Cat.setValue(option.price, forKey: "Price")
            Cat.setValue(option.Desc, forKey: "Description")
            Cat.setValue(option.isrequired, forKey: "IsRequired")
            // let array = JSON(Cat)
            options.append(Cat)}
    }


    let prepared: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()

    prepared.setValue(PreparationTime.MinTime, forKey: "MinTime")
    prepared.setValue(PreparationTime.MinCount, forKey: "MinCount")
    prepared.setValue(PreparationTime.AdditionalPerItem, forKey: "AdditionalPerItem")
    //let pre = JSON(prepared)

     let pricingdata: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
   pricingdata.setValue(Pricing.Price, forKey: "Price")
      pricingdata.setValue(Pricing.SalePrice, forKey: "SalePrice")
      pricingdata.setValue(Pricing.SaleStart, forKey: "SaleStart")
      pricingdata.setValue(Pricing.SaleEnd, forKey: "SaleEnd")
   // let pricingd = JSON(pricingdata)
    let param = [  "Name" : Name,
                   "BusinessId" : BusinessId,
                   "Sku" : Sku,
                   "Menus":categories,
                   "Cuisines":cuisineList,
                   "Attributes":attributeList,
        "Description":Description,
        "PreparationTime": prepared ,
        "Pricing":pricingdata,
        "Customizations":options
       ] as [String : Any]



    self._webApiHelper.SendHttpRequest(params: param as AnyObject, header_obj: headers,  url: "Vendor/Menu/Items/Add", http_method: .post) { (response_value, error) in
        print(response_value)

        if(error != "NO_INT"){
            if(response_value["Message"].string! == "SUCCESS")
            {
                completion(response_value["Message"].string! ,response_value["Id"].string!,"")
            }
            else{
                completion(response_value["Message"].string!,"" ,"")

            }



        }
        else{

            completion( "","",response_value["Message"].string!)
        }
    }//SendHttpRequest
}
```

this is the webapihelper method

```
var BASE_URL : String = "http://portal.blueicon.lk/api/"
var TOKEN_URL: String = "http://portal.blueicon.lk/token"


func SendHttpRequest(params: AnyObject, header_obj: [String: String], url:String, http_method:HTTPMethod, completion: @escaping (_ response_value: JSON, _ error_type: String)->()) {

    Alamofire.request(BASE_URL + url, method: http_method, parameters: (params as! [String : Any]) , encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: header_obj).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

        switch(response.result) {
        case .success( _ ):

            if let jsonValue = response.result.value {
                let json = JSON(jsonValue)
                completion(json, "")
            }
            break

        case .failure(_):
            print(response.result.error!)
            completion(JSON(response.result.value), "NO_INT")
            //"The Internet connection appears to be offline."
            break

        }
    }//Alamofire

}//SendHttpRequest
```

Answer (score 0):

**The problem in your Code**:

```
"Pricing":pricingdata
```

you can't pass the Dictionary in param.

**Solution:**

you need to convert Dictionary To JSON String then only your Problem will resolve to use this **extension** to convert into String the passed string in your param.

```
extension NSDictionary {
    func toJSonString() -> String {

        let dict = self
        var jsonString = "";

        do {

            let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: .prettyPrinted)
            jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String

        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        return jsonString;
    }
}
```

I hope it will work.